# display: inline on checkbox and label not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

I want to put a checkbox with a label to its right in my simple webpage, but when I select the `label` and `checkbox` to change their `display`, they both behave differently.

When checkbox is set to inline, it moves up to the right of textarea who's display is set to block. So I figured I can just set checkbox display to block and label display to inline and the label will move to the right of block. Instead, the label stays below the checkbox and eliminates any margin between it and the send button.

How can I fix this?

The code is in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/cacupij/6/edit?html,css,output)

The form is a child of `.main-body`

#### HTML

```
<form>
  <label for="name-input">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name-input">
  <label for="message-input">Message</label>
  <textarea id="message-input"></textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" id="current-user">
  <label for="current-user">I currently use SuiteLyfe</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

#### CSS

```
.main-body {
  display: box;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
textarea[id=message-input] {
  display: box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
}
label[for=current-user] {
  display: inline;
}
```

**P.S.** I'm aware of bootstrap and other technologies but right now I am learning barebones html and css and wish to understand it even though I realize it may not matter in my career.

Comment: You can simplify your HTML by putting each checkbox inside its associated label. This normally makes the label appear beside the checkbox with just the default styles. E.g. `<label><input type="checkbox" id="current-user"> I currently use SuiteLyfe</label>`

Comment: Also, I'm fairly sure that "box" isn't a valid option for the `display` property, and would therefore be ignored by the browser. You presumably meant to use "block".

Comment: Yeah that was the problem! Such a dumb mistake, but I wasn't picking it up on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your textarea display type to `block` and your checkbox display type to `inline`

```
textarea[id=message-input] {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see it now, my mistake!